# apt-get update on Debian 8 upgraded to 9 repository: signature error

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I made own repository, signed by my gpg key.
I have at home 3 pc; the new Debian 9, and 2 upgraded Debians from 8 to 9.
On my one computer (8->9)  - I don't know why (the other 2 installs correct my packet)  I got this error (see below).
My question is: how to clean apt cache - but not .deb files, only list which I get after calling `# apt-get update`?

my errors:

at first: a lot of lines (not shown on my other computers)

```
> ...
> Ign:24 https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free all DEP-11 Metadata
> Ign:25 https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
> Ign:13 https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free all Packages Błąd:17
> https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free amd64 Packages  
> gnutls_handshake() failed: Public key signature verification has
> failed. Ign:18 https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free Translation-pl
> Ign:20 https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free Translation-en Ign:22
> https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free Translation-pl_PL Ign:23
> https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata Ign:24
> https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free all DEP-11 Metadata Ign:25
> https://aaa.com/debian stretch/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons ...
```

and then at the end:

```
W: The repository 'https://aaa.com/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Nie udało się pobrać https://aaa.com/debian/dists/stretch/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: Public key signature verification has failed.
```

in my sources.list I have:

```
deb https://aaa.com/debian stretch non-free
```

How I do my repo? :

```
#!/bin/bash

cd repoX
rm -r ./debian
rm -r ./repo/dists
rm -r ./repo/pool
rm -r ./repo/db


mkdir -p debian
debsigs --sign=origin -k XXXXXXXX  ../DebianR/debian.deb
debsigs --sign=maint -k XXXXXXXX  ../DebianR/debian.deb
debsigs --sign=archive -k XXXXXXXX  ../DebianR/debian.deb
mv ../DebianR/debian.deb debian/debian-1.0_amd64.deb
reprepro --confdir ./repo/conf/ includedeb stretch ./debian/debian-1.0_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

You must import the gpg key of your repository into apt:

```
gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys XXXXXXXX
gpg -a --export XXXXXXXX | sudo apt-key add -
```

the `XXXXXXXX` should really be your **long** fingerprint (40 chars, rather than 8), as there are the short (8 char) fingerprints can easily be spoofed. This is *not* a theoretical problem; there *are* already fake networks with spoofed short fingerprints, e.g. [evil32](https://evil32.com/). If your short fingerprint has been spoofed and you happen to add the short fingerprint to your apt-keys, you are basically allowing somebody else to sign your packages.

Also make sure, that your key has not expired.
(i was recently bitten by that myself :-))

Comment: thanks, i did IT (for future), but its doesent solve my problem, btw. key is pretty new and expires after 10 years